# Consume an AUTO ML Machine learning forecasting passing to a values of csv file

Tags: python, forecasting, azure-machine-learning-service

I have successfully run an AUTO ML forecasting model on Azure Machine Learning. Model is deployed on container service.

I would like to pass on a bunch of test values to the model from csv and generate forecast for a set of two variables, i.e. cluster and week number. The same options are available in Azure ML test functionality but how do I pass it on to all the csv values I have?

I tried using powerBI but it errors out once I try to apply the model. After reading 215 kb of file, it fails with error "context deadline exceeded"

[image]

I also tried to invoke the rest endpoint via excel add in - but it errors out saying bad url.

What's the easy way to pass on all the values of csv to rest endpoint and consume the result and store it back to csv?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of testing the deployed service, in my opinion, is by modifying the consumption code pre-generated by Azure Machine Learning.

This code is available C#, Python and R. You can get it from Azure Machine Learning workspace > Endpoints > Select your deployed inference service > Select the tab Consume. The sample HTTP call is completely agnostic from the SDK, meaning that it should work on any environment without having to install any client.

Once you get access to this code, you can modify the json containing the sample data ("example_value") to pass to the service by the data is present in the csv. In Python, for instance, this is easily accomplished with `Pandas.read_csv()` method.

Eventually, you can modify the json to pass more than 1 record at the time. The output response will be modified accordingly.

Please, pay attention that the json must contain strings and must be encoded to be used in the HTTP protocol.